# What is the best query other than ADD UNIQUE or SELECT GROUP BY to remove duplicates

Tags: mysql

What is the best query other than `ADD UNIQUE` or `SELECT GROUP BY` to remove duplicates in the large table of 100 million records?

In the contact details table (InnoDB) that I have contains 100 million records with 15 columns. It took 12 minutes to run the below query to group 1 record:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE field1='aaa' AND field2='bbb' AND field3='ccc' AND field4='ddd' AND field5='eee' 
GROUP BY field1, field2, field3, field4, field5
```

And 0.275ms for the below query with 5000 samples from the table:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE table 
    ADD UNIQUE(field1(255),field2(255),field3(255),field4(255),field5(255))
```

Comment: adding unique constraint will remove duplicate rows permanently

Comment: Do you want to remove duplicates from the table or from the query results?

Comment: @jussius. From the table. I gave a try to `SELECT` query after discovered `ALTER IGNORE TABLE` query take ages to run.

Comment: "SELECT *" and "GROUP BY" together is never going to make any sense.

Comment: @Dhay Just run that ALTER TABLE. It will take ages with 100 million records but you only have to run it once. And after that your queries will be much faster as you don't want to use group by or distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best for removing duplicate withou group by or unique clause is `distinct`

```
 SELECT distinct   field1, field2, field3, field4, field5 FROM table 
 WHERE field1='aaa' 
 AND field2='bbb' 
 AND field3='ccc' 
 AND field4='ddd'
 AND field5='eee'
```

(you should avoid select *  in this case)

Comment: Just FYI, the optimizer will most likely turn this into exact same query as the one with GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT. But I agree using DISTINCT is probably better style.

Comment: I accept the point. I accept this as answer for better styling even the query takes time as the same as `ALTER IGNORE TABLE`

Comment: @Dhay   . thanks  .. remeber that the disctinct clause is a DML clause and you can use avioiding the  database schema change while alter table is a DDL operation and change the database schema  .. this mean that if you need a unique constrains you should palin it before the query  wihile use distinct on noy is an application requirement ..